# Literal search in Kibana (Lucene)

Tags: lucene, kibana

I'm trying to search for all documents that contain the term PHPSESSID=; but even when using "PHPSESSID=;" it just brings up everything that has "PHPSESSID". How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your fields are analyzed don't I think it's normal. You need to create a raw field I think.

Comment: There is a raw field, but it doesn't search on it. E.g. cookie.raw:"PHPSESSID" gives no results.